# All Windows app icons showing the same

Tags: windows, windows-10, icons, windows-10-apps

Hopefully someone can shed some light on this...

When I access the start menu, all apps are displayed as you would expect, with the correct icons

However, when I click the magnifying glass at the side, all apps which are directly related to windows (ones which I have not installed from an external source) including pre-installed apps such as Spotify, all are displayed with the same logo as the following pic shows

[image]

Does anyone know what might have caused this? And, how I might rectify it?

Comment: Try to [Rebuild Corrupt Icon Cache](https://www.thewindowsclub.com/rebuild-icon-clear-thumbnail-cache-windows-10).

Comment: @harrymc I have tried that but it wouldnt delete the icon cache, kept saying `This action cannot be completed because the file is open in windows explorer` Tried also using the command line but I got `access denied`. After you replied I thought Id try again in safe mode, but got the same result

Comment: Did you delete the files at `C:\Users\%username%\AppData\Local\Microsoft\Windows\Explorer`?

Comment: @harrymc I tried deleting the files but it did not work. I used the command taskkill explorer.exe and it still didnt work

Answer (score 0):

I havefound a solution on https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/all/default-image-icon-when-searching-for-app-in/e9afef63-7c2e-4367-ad5a-391c21d9736d

```
Press Windows key+R to open Run then copy and paste the full path below:
%localappdata%\Packages\Microsoft.Windows.Search_cw5n1h2txyewy\LocalState\AppIconCache

Press Enter
An explorer window will pop-out
find 100 and rename it to 100.bak.
Restart your computer
```

Answer (score -2):

Had this same issue. Almost every icon on my taskbar and most icons on my desktop looked the same. After trying these other suggestions with no luck, this solution below did the trick and it didn't require any technical Windows surgery:

Windows Key + i;
System -> Display;
Change Scale up 1 factor (IE: from 100% (Recommended) to 125%);
Reboot;
Do the above steps again, but revert your Scale back to original value;
Reboot;
All done!

My icons actually refreshed when I scaled up by 1 factor, but I did all of the steps just to be thorough. Shout out to the MS guy who suggested this fix!